# Is it normal for the Azure Function Runtime to release a blob listener?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a Azure Function (v2) (edit: on a consumption plan) that fails to run when blobs are changed in the container it is monitoring.  If I manually jump-start the function to run by viewing it on the Azure Portal, it processes all blobs since last run, as expected.  After less than 10 minutes, however, it seems like it stops polling the container:

```
Hosting stopping
Stopping JobHost
Singleton lock released (cafectoweretl/WebJobs.Internal.Blobs.Listener)
```

I'm trying to understand what is happening behind the scenes here.  Is the Function runtime polling the container (or the logs) outside of the WebJobs.Internal.Blobs.Listener?  If so, where is this activity logged?

Comment: Does the azure function have a blob trigger?

Comment: Yes, it has a blob trigger

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions shut down after a while if there are no triggers to be executed. Normally it would start again once an event is available for processing. Enable "Always On" on your app service plan which would keep at least one instance of the function running.

More about always on in this answer [How do I turn on "always-on" for an Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430932/how-do-i-turn-on-always-on-for-an-azure-function)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So, if I understand correctly, JobHost and the Blobs.Listener are part of the "Azure function" that shuts down.  What is monitoring for change events if not the listener?  I am on a consumption plan, so "Always On" is not an option (sorry, failed to detail this in original message).

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/08/07/why-does-my-azure-function-sometimes-stop-being-triggered/  maybe this helps.