# Azure Service Bus Function Not Running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have a function set up with `ServiceBusTrigger` which runs when it is deployed and then keeps running while I'm testing and sending messages to a topic. However, if I wait an hour or so and then send more messages they are not processed until I either restart the function app or disable and reenable the actual function.

How can I change this so that the function is always "on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a dedicated App Service Plan. Make sure you have "Always On" enabled. You need to have at least a "Basic" plan. If you don't want to pay for a basic plan, I suggest you use a consumption plan.

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Enable-Always-On-when-running-on-dedicated-App-Service-Plan

[How do I turn on "always-on" for an Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430932/how-do-i-turn-on-always-on-for-an-azure-function)