# Change "Always On" setting for Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I've an Azure Function App - created with the setting "Always On" and a matching AppServicePlan behind.

Now, I want to change the setting of "Always On" to false/off ... but I couldn't find the setting neither in Settings->Configuration nor in other tabs like Settings-->Properties.

Do I have to delete my function app and recreate it with "Always On" = false or is there another way to change this setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn on "always-on" for an Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430932/how-do-i-turn-on-always-on-for-an-azure-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In App service plan or  premium plan you can change the always on option as below:

[image]

- Whereas in Consumption plan, you cannot change it.
- If you want to change it frequently, you can use other plan such as Dedicated or Premium.

Answer (score 0):

There are [three different hosting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#overview-of-plans) for your Azure Functions (Consumption plan, Premium plan and dedicated plan).

You are probably using the first (Consumption plan, which scales automatically and you only pay for compute resources when your functions are running. In this hosting option, you don't have the Always On setting.